# 1px border messing up with 100% width split page

Tags: css, width, border

so lets say I want 80% page red, 20% page blue. It works.

But if I add a 1px border to any of them, it is ruined.

```
 .left {
        float:left; 
        width: 80%;
        background-color: red;
        height: 400px;
        border-right:1px solid black;

    }

.right {
float: right;
    background-color: blue;

    height: 400px;
    width: 20%;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38w4pLg0/

Can I have a border without ruining it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`box-sizing: border-box`

---

Set this property on the boxes. The total size of the box will now be made to **include** the border.

By default, this property is set to `content-box` which only counts the box's interior - padding + border are excluded from the calculations.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

---

Example for your question:

```
.left {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Or, preferred, add a new class for all of the boxes:

```
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `box-sizing: border-box;`

What it does it wont let the border add width/height to the box and will contain it inside.

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/38w4pLg0/6/